# parsing string in JSON three.js

Tags: json, three.js, webgl

I am new to Three.js. My need is to get "DbgName": "mtl" from JSON file using Three.js's JSONLoader. 
Here my sample three.js's JSON file

```
{"metadata" :
{"formatVersion" : 3.1,
"sourceFile" : "json",
"generatedBy" : "json",
"vertices" : 20,
"faces" : 81,
"normals" : 0,
"colors" : 0,
"uvs" : 0,
"materials" : 4},

"scale" : 1.000000,
"materials": [{
"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "mtl1",
"colorAmbient" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
"colorDiffuse" : [0.64, 0.64, 0.64],
"colorSpecular" : [0.165, 0.165, 0.165],
"illumination" : 2,
"opticalDensity" : 1.0,
"specularCoef" : 154.901961,
"transparency" : 1.0
}
]}
```

Could any one give some suggestion for the same..Thanks

Comment: Please if you edit your post, check the code formatting. It is horrible again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the material name from json file by this way...

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(url,function(geometry,material){
....some code stuff........
var mName = materials.name;
....some code stuff.....
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.JSONLoader` is not a generic JSON loader: it loads meshes and materials from JSON files that have specific properties.

For loading your own stuff, you could still take (copy-paste) the AJAX request part of the loader, which is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r56/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js#L29

Note that once you've gotten the file text, parsing it to a JS object is [trivially accomplished](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r56/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js#L43) with standard browser provided function: `var mystuff = JSON.parse(fileTextContents)`

Comment: {
"metadata" :{
"formatVersion" : three,
"sourceFile" : "three",
"generatedBy" : "three",
"vertices" : 6,
"faces" : 10,
"normals" : 0,
"colors" : 0,
"uvs" : 0,
"materials" : 1
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials": [{"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "Meterial1" }]
..............,} It's my sample JSON file. i would like to read the "DbgName" using THREE.js's JSONLoader.

Comment: You should have said that in the first place - `DbgName` is put into the corresponding material's `name` property ([source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r56/src/loaders/Loader.js#L435))